# Creating custom grid control in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, custom-controls

I need to create a custom grid like control in Silverlight which shows data, in the following format.

[image]

Each Cell will contain the value that represents the intersection. How can I do this with silverlight?

PS: The numbers don't mean real values.

Comment: You want the normal column heading to be in the bottom right? other than the grid look same as normal grid. If it is the case, pass the heading data also a row in the row collection. Will that not work?

Comment: @Nair Thanks for the comment. I Heading data position is not a concern. I can move them to the top. Now my question is, instead of having the numerical data, can I have an image which represents the data quantity like color gradient, or a bubble??

Comment: yes, you can use converters for each type and in the converter, instead of returning test, you can return image and then bind to the column like http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=583